# What is the meaning of 偽り者

Tags: meaning

Is it imposter “ or something that is fake that is not necessarily human? Can it be both about a person and a thing?

Comment: It is not a common word today. Do you have a context where it appeared?

Comment: An episode title

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very common word in today's language. According to [the dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%81%BD%E3%82%8A%E8%80%85/):

> うそをつく人。いつわりびと。
>
> 「わらはを―にせうと云ふ事か」〈虎明狂・塗師〉

Its meaning is "liar", which is a human. The word seems to be used at several places in the Japanese Bible translations.

> 偽り者とは、イエスがキリストであることを否定する者でなくて、誰のことでしょうか。御父と御子を否定する者、これこそ反キリストです。
> *Who is the liar but he who denies that Jesus is the Christ? This is the antichrist, he who denies the Father and the Son.* (1 John 2:22, ESV)

Comment: Isn’t “mono” used for non humans too though? I saw in some dictionary that it can be “ counterfeit” too

Comment: @Onna Potentially yes but many words are actually fixed on either "human" or "thing". They have kanji difference: 者 for human sense and 物 for thing. Do you mean 偽物【にせもの】 for "counterfeit"?

Comment: no, still itsuwarimono. Apparently it’s how the word was translated in the subbed version too

Comment: @Onna I can't find a word "itsuwarimono" that means something like "fake thing" and I don't remember such a word exists. I think it may be either a creative usage or the subber's mistake.

Comment: Maybe counterfeit can be used on a person so they meant someone who is fake